# PHP is creating two rows in my table, One ok, but extra empty

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo

I'm testing a form. When I click in submit one row is created correcly with the infos, but an extra row is creating with no information. How can I cancel this second creating? Thanks.

My form code:

```
  <section class="cadastro-consultoras-inicio">
    <div class="w100 text-centralized">
      <h1 class="destaque-roxo">As mães estão esperando por você</h1>
        <p>Preencha as informações abaixo e você fará parte do nosso grupo de parceiras.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w33 auto">
      <form id="formulario-consultoras" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formulario-consultoras" action="ajax/cadastrar-consultoras.php">
        <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome">
        <input type="text" name="sobrenome" placeholder="Sobrenome" >
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" >
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Senha">
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone" >
        <input type="text" name="cidade" placeholder="Cidade" >
        <br><br>
        <input class="outline-button" type="submit" name="acao" value="ENVIAR">
      </form><!--formulario-->
      
    </div>
  </section>
```

And the action php file:

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "Hera";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `tb_consultoras_cadastradas` (email, nome, sobrenome, telefone, senha, cidade)
  VALUES ('".$_POST["email"]."','".$_POST["nome"]."','".$_POST["sobrenome"]."','".$_POST["telefone"]."','".$_POST["password"]."','".$_POST["cidade"]."')";
  // use exec() because no results are returned
  $conn->exec($sql);
  echo "New record created successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;

?>
```

Thanks again.

Comment: I guess somehow the action file is called twice and since there is no checks that prevent the DB-Insert if there is no data sent, it just creates empty an entry.

Comment: On a side note, instead of exec() you must use prepare/execute with parameters instead of variables

Comment: Is there any JavaScript/Ajax function that gets called on the submit event? If so, use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the form from sending as usual.